# Internal circuits in 8051 to handle an External interrupts0 and External interrupts1

Tags: interrupts, 8051

Can you explain me the internal circuits in 8051 to handle interrupts in 8051
external interrupt0
external interrrupt1
timer0
timer1
serial interrupt
and also for reset with respect to 8051.

hope, i will get clear explanation

Thank you

Comment: First we need a clear question.

Answer (score 2):

Not Sure about Your question, But I guess this might help you:

[8051 Interrupt Structure](http://www.slideshare.net/SiliconLabs/8051-microcontroller-interrupt-architecture)